# How to autoplay music with <audio> tags (NOT with <audio autoplay>)

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="punch-high1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

x.loop = true;
x.autoplay = true;
x.load();

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I'm currently using to test out Autoplay with the audio tags. But it's not working, I have tested it with the horse.mp3 from w3schools and made it match this code EXACTLY how it is, but this code still doesn't work while the code from w3schools that I modified does. And I have tried using autoplay within the first audio tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you looked at what `x` is returning?

Comment: Where did you get `load()`? I did not see it in doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: is the file available for running?

Answer (score 1):

After Chrome 66 update, you need to manually change your Chrome settings so that the autoplay works.

**Steps to follow:**

1. Type `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` in the URL
2. In the dropdown, select "*No user gesture is required*".
3. Relaunch Chrome.

P.S.: You do not require `x.load()` statement in your code.

Comment: It just says "This site can’t be reached. chrome’s server IP address could not be found." when I try to load into the link

Comment: @SPARKST3R3556: You don't have to include http protocol in the URL. Edited the answer.